# How to create internal RTC Timer interrupt of 100ms using PSoC 5LP in PSoC creator without making PSoC sleep?

Tags: c, embedded, psoc, cypress-psoc

I want to create interrupt of 100ms using internal RTC of PSoC 5lp. I am using this RTC interrupt as time out interrupt for receiving command from UART communication. I want PSoC to be in active state when RTC interrupt is received.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the datasheet? I find that the  answer is almost always there to find.

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to use the RTC rather than using a Timer component?  I'm not sure you can use the RTC for an interrupt with that short a period.  There are built in ISR stubs that can be fired every second, minute, hour, day, week, month, and year.  They can be enabled with the RTC_WriteIntervalMask() function (see pg24 in the RTC component datasheet)